# Azure pipeline SQL Migration Ef Core Object exist issue

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using `.NET Core 6`, `EF Core Code first` to deploy my application and DB in Azure App services using pipelines.

Using the pipeline task for `SQL Migration` I generate the `.sql` file and deploy it in DB using release pipeline.

Now the migration file is generated with `CREATE TABLE` script and its getting deployed as well. The issue here is when I change the model file (any column changes like `Add` or `Delete` or changes in `MaxLength`) and deploy it again, the same file gets generated with `CREATE TABLE` script and during deployment it says `TABLE NAME xyz already EXISTS`.

I'm expecting something like what `DACPAC` task do, verify and handle itself. Or is there any way that from Migration a `DACPAC` file can be generated.

Anyone can help?

**SQL Migration Task:**

```
migrations add DbMigration --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\NotificationService.App/NotificationService.App.csproj
```

**Create Script Task:**

```
migrations script  --idempotent --output $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SQL/migrations.sql --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\NotificationService.App/NotificationService.App.csproj --context NotificationDbContext
```

**SQL Deployment:**

Happens in release pipeline using `Azure Sql Database Deplpyment` task with `Deploy Type` as `Sql Script File`.

[image: Deployment Task in Release pipeline]

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NotificationDbContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionStringValue.Value,
        sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions => {
            sqlOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable("EFMigrationHistory", "dbo");
            sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(NotificationDbContext).Assembly.GetName().Name);
            sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 15, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
        });
}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

**DbContext:**

```
public class NotificationDbContext : DbContext
 {
     public NotificationDbContext(DbContextOptions<NotificationDbContext> options)
         : base(options)
     {
     
     }

     public DbSet<Notification> Notification { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }

 }

 public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<NotificationDbContext>
 {
     public NotificationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
     {
         var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NotificationDbContext>();
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString..."
             , options => {
                 options.MigrationsHistoryTable("EFMigrationHistory", "dbo");
             });

         return new NotificationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
     }
    
 }
```

**Error:**

[image: Error message in deployment]

Comment: How you deploy the sql file in Release Pipeline? Can you share more details?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Deployment is in release pipeline using `Azure Sql Database Deplpyment` task with `Deploy Type` as `Sql Script File`.

Comment: To get more details, [that link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1/README.md#troubleshooting-)  recommends "On the Variables tab, add `system.debug` and set it to `true`."

Comment: @CrazyPyro I clearly know what's the issue is, anything more to debug here?